# How can we resume a persisted workflow in wf 4?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow with one state machine. I persist my workflow in half way. Now I want to reload this workflow and resume the work. What is the solution?
I persist my workflow by `SqlWorkflowInstanceStore` class on sql server 2008 database.

Comment: I'll upvote you just because you are one of the few users of WF4 :-) But your question is quite lacking. What are you using for storage? You should post some code snippet/some description of what you are doing.

Comment: Look if this is enough as an example: [WF4 host resumes delayed workflow (CSWF4LongRunningHost)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSWF4LongRunningHost-5960e8d3)

Comment: @xanatos: thanks, Is there any difference between resuming a sequence and state machine?

Comment: I don't use WF4, but I would think there isn't. But the only way to try is to check. :-)

Comment: @masoudramezani: is that your real question?  Seems like you were just asking how to bookmark and resume.

Comment: Questions like this one are easily answered with a look on the official [WF and WCF Samples](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21459). Dozens of samples for particular cases and general scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look here for a detailed example on how to work with WF 4 and SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.

[WF 4 Persistence, Tracking, and Bookmarks: A Practical Approach](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/WF4Extensions.aspx)

Comment: That's not exactly an answer, its more of a comment.

Comment: For reference, if you are using `WorkflowApplication` the relevant sample is `WF\Basic\Services\AbsoluteDelay`. Although it's still way too much code (100 lines?!!) for something that should be one or two lines out of the box!

Answer (score -2):

Just install Windows Server AppFabric.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question. Just suggesting to install yet another MS product is not a good solution for most people. Plus, this changes the hosting environment which is also not ideal.

Comment: Disagree. The formulation of the question strongly suggests that the SqlInstanceStore is incidental and corollary to the question.

Comment: You're right, it is an option. I think in most cases it won't be a good option, but that doesn't make your answer wrong. I have un-downvoted. Sorry. I should have read better. Wait, can I!?